# iOS SQLite Mach-O errors on simulator, not iPhone (4)

Tags: ios, compiler-errors

I'm getting a bunch of Linker errors when trying to compile my app in the simulator, but none when compiling it to my phone. Could someone take a look at them and take a guess as to what is going on?

I have libsqlite3.dylib in my app.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/monkeyButt/Desktop/Development/XCodeApps/knowInk Publishing - Medicare Providers Locator/libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController initSQLiteDB] in SQLiteController.o
      -[SQLiteController getData] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController initSQLiteDB] in SQLiteController.o
      -[SQLiteController insertData:::] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController initSQLiteDB] in SQLiteController.o
      -[SQLiteController getData] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController insertData:::] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController insertData:::] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController getData] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController getData] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController getData] in SQLiteController.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[SQLiteController getData] in SQLiteController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error (didn't try it on an iOS device though) and I added libsqlite3.0.dylib and got it to work on the simulator.  Hope this helps!